# Loop in write xml for treeview

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, wpf, treeview

I read data from a SQL database in a Web Form application and write that into a XML file and show them using TreeView control. But the problem is that I can read only the Trees with ParentID 0 from database and show them using TreeView. How can I show sub-trees also, having ParentID 1 on the TreeView ?
 reading from database :

```
public DataTable GetMenu(int parentId)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source =(Local);Initial Catalog=Tajari;Integrated Security=True;"))
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from TBLJobs where ParentId=@ParentId", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParentId", parentId);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        con.Close();
        return dt;
    }
}
```

Creating a XML file code :

```
private void CreateNodes(int parentId)
{
    DataTable dt = GetMenu(0);
    foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement("Node");
        writer.WriteStartAttribute("Id");
        writer.WriteValue(dr["MenuId"].ToString());
        writer.WriteEndAttribute();

        writer.WriteStartAttribute("Name");
        writer.WriteValue(dr["MenuName"].ToString());
        writer.WriteEndAttribute();

        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }
}
```

writing to the XML file using XMLWriter

```
public void CreateMenu()
{
    using (writer = XmlWriter.Create(Server.MapPath("Temp\\Menu.XML")))
    {
        writer.WriteStartDocument();
        writer.WriteStartElement("Menu");
        CreateNodes(0);
        writer.WriteEndDocument();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void CreateNodes(int parentId)
{
    DataTable dt = GetMenu(0);
    foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement("Node");
        writer.WriteStartAttribute("Id");
        writer.WriteValue(dr["MenuId"].ToString());
        writer.WriteEndAttribute();

        writer.WriteStartAttribute("Name");
        writer.WriteValue(dr["MenuName"].ToString());
        writer.WriteEndAttribute();

        **CreateNodes(Convert.ToInt32(dr["MenuId"]));**
        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }
}
```